# Can I send data to Google Analytics Measurement Protocol from Amazon Elastic Beanstalk application?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I have a website running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.5.0 running PHP 7.0).

Is there an app or service I can run on this server to automatically send all hits etc to Google Analytics using the Measurement Protocol?

I want to avoid having the user load the analytics JavaScript file.

Comment: have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51153999/4050261